# Conversion of React Javascript to React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Box, Button} from "@material-ui/core";

class Counter extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        count : 5,

    }
}

increment() {
    this.setState({
        count : this.state.count + 1,
    });
}

decrement() {
    this.setState({
        count : this.state.count - 1,
    })
}

render() {

    return(
        <div>
            <Button variant="contained" color = "primary" size="large" onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}> + </Button>
            <Box component="span" margin={5}> {this.state.count} </Box>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" onClick={this.decrement.bind(this)}> - </Button>
        </div>
    )
}}export default Counter;
```

I want to change React code in JavaScript to React code in TypeScript.
But I don't know how to change that code.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Hi, when you are using the previous state value in setState, use 
this.setState((prevState, prevProps)=>({count: prevState.count + 1}) 
rather than the above code, as state updates may be asynchronous.
See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your header:
To specify the return type of a method simply state it after the args

```
function(): void { ... } // void can also be number, string etc
```

To your question in the body:
This is a very broad and non specific question.
To learn how to write in Typescript I recommend that you refer to the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/
Or use other methods of learning such as videos etc.

Comment: thank you. I checked the answer now. Thanks to you, I learned a lot of good information. I hope you are always full of happy things.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code which you would like in `typescript` format:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Box, Button } from "@material-ui/core";

type CounterProps = {};

type CounterState = {
  count: number;
};

class Counter extends Component<CounterProps, CounterState> {
  constructor(props: CounterProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 5
    };
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  }

  decrement() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count - 1
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="large"
          onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}
        >
          {" "}
          +{" "}
        </Button>
        <Box component="span" margin={5}>
          {" "}
          {this.state.count}{" "}
        </Box>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="large"
          onClick={this.decrement.bind(this)}
        >
          {" "}
          -{" "}
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default function App() {
  return <Counter />;
}
```

[image: Edit goofy-http-ln5bu]

Comment: thank you. I checked the answer now. Thanks to you, I learned a lot of good information. I hope you are always full of happy things.

Answer (score 0):

You can create interfaces (or types) for both state and props and pass them while creating the class. The answer from [majid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14986372/majid-m) has it covered. That will also allow you to control the code and leaks better.

Try creating a sample project using `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` and check the code. It has a lot of insight for you to begin with. Very straightforward and intuitive.

Comment: thank you. I checked the answer now. Thanks to you, I learned a lot of good information. I hope you are always full of happy things.